# "Library/Search/propertyDatabase.db" is already opened

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

While I was making my game after i edited a script this annoying error appeard:

> The property database "Library/Search/propertyDatabase.db" is already opened.
> UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_InvokeTickEvents ()

If you need it I'm using *Unity 2022.1.1.0f1*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart your computer to make the engine work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I was using the same prefab in more than one scene and using different scaling transform. Once I made a and use a copy of the prefab instead, that rectified the pesky issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I had opened another project instead of the current project and that project will be also stored in a temp file, I figure out that maybe that's my problem so I delete the temp folder project and restart the current project now the error will disappear

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).